# Android "application-global" thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-sqlite

I have an application, which consists of 3 activities. In the first activity I start thread in onCreate() and stop it in onDestroy(), so I hope this thread will work while application running. In this thread I read data from database and send it to the server.

Main question: Is there right way to do this work, or first activity can be destroyed while application works? How to do that in the right way?

Side question: Due to multi-write to the database problem, is there a way to create class, which will manage SQLite writing and which will be accessible from every activity?

I think about using Application class, but have some doubts about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot rely on an activity not being destroyed when it is no longer needed, even if the rest of the application is active. You might be able to have *all* of your activities able to start/stop the thread though, and use an application global reference counter so you know when you want to start the thread again or just increase your reference count.

Regarding your database management class, it's ok to have multiple instances of your class; the SQLite database you're managing is thread-safe. If you have some other reason to have just a single instance of your helper, you can create it using the Singleton pattern such that the first client to access it creates the instance, and all subsequent clients get its pointer.

Comment: Maybe i don't understand "thread-safe" word right, but after reading a couple of stackoverflow questions and answers, i got, that there is no write-locking protect in android SQLite. And i can read from a lot of threads, but i must write only in one thread. I want to create global class with its own stack of data, which i will write to the database in separate thread, but i should have access to this stack from every activity.

Comment: As I said, if you're concerned about multiple thread access, using a singleton as your helper class (or at least using a helper class with static member objects you synchronize on) will solve this for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sending data to server is usually not continous operation but repeatable job-type op, so it looks you shall rather use `IntentService` instead of Thread. Also setting in `onCreate` and destroying in `onDestroy` is not a best approach as your thread will be running even if application is in background (which usually means it will be of no use). Extending Application is quite ok, but I think you do not need to go that far.

Answer (score 0):

The Application class can be used to manage application-global stuff. Whenever running a thread all the time is a good idea is another question.

1. Implement an android.app.Application subclass. Should be in the root of your application package.

   ```
   package com.yourapp;        

   public class YourApplication extends Application {
       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
           // [...]
       }
       // [...]
   }
   ```
2. Specify application class in the AndroidManifest.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             package="com.yourapp"
             android:versionName="1.0"
             android:versionCode="1.0">
       <application android:name="YourApplication"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:icon="@drawable/icon">
       <!-- ... -->
       </application>
   </manifest>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

- for the first question, use `IntentService` to do the communication with the server.
- for the second question, extend the `SQLiteOpenHelper` class and make it a Singleton.
  that's it.